# 13x13 grid, fill each cell with multiple colors on user input

Tags: python

I am trying to create a NLHE poker preflop hand chart (13 x 13 matrix) gui in python 3.5. 
I need each box in the table (1 box = 1 hand combination) to be filled with multiple colors (to signify different actions being taken). 
The colors in each box will correspond to user input (so something like "AA r:75 c:25" is going to tell the box for hand AA to fill with 75% of color1 and 25% of color2.

The end result should look something like this:

[image: End result Image]

I'm not sure how to go about this.
I can get turtle graphics to make (13x13=169) individual boxes with fill colors, and use variables like turtle.fd(AAr) / turtle.fd(AAc), but I'm not sure if this is the best method. I'd also prefer the ability to resize the gui and have the 13x13 grid expand/shrink with it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why only 13x13, for simplicity?  This doesn't distinguish between, e.g. AK off-suit vs AK suited.

Comment: Amit Kumar Gupta, 
13 x 13 does distinguish AKo (offsuit) and AKs (suited) as shown in the attached image in my OP.

Comment: My bad, I see it. Nice.

Comment: NP. Any idea how to achieve it? :)

Comment: zetysz, I thought about that, but it doesn't seem like the most viable solution. at the least i'd need 5% increments, and upwards of 4-5 colors. that would be a crazy amount of images to create manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this quite easily with tkinter. Make a class that creates one square by aligning 4 or 10 or 100 rectangles. Then, you can color the various rectangles according to whatever scheme you have. Once you have that, it's a simple matter to make a grid of these squares.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably easier to read the chart if each square had one color that varied depending on hand strength, accompanied by a small legend. Like this:

[image]

[Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) is part of the Python stdlib.

Here's some basic code to do the grid and colors. This currently just randoms a hex color for each square, but you would have to create a dictionary with each hand and color code for strength.

```
import Tkinter
import random

c = "AKQJT98765432"
r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)

root = Tkinter.Tk()
[Tkinter.Label(root, text=i+j, bg='#%02X%02X%02X'%(r(),r(),r())).grid(\
row=c.index(i), column=c.index(j)) for i in c for j in c]
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey vesche, I appreciate the post (and might find that useful for something in the near future, so saving it) but that isn't what I need. 

I specifically need it to display different colors within a cell to indicate 'mixing' strategies (so red in 75% of the cell, and green in 25% of the cell is saying "raise 75% of the time, and call 25% of the time").